# Add new user in solaris

Tags: solaris, useradd

I tried to add a new user in solaris 10, but got an error:

```
$ useradd -g oinstall -G dba -d /export/home/oracle oracle
UX: useradd: ERROR: Inconsistent password files.  See pwconv(1M).
```

I ran `pwconv`, but nothing was displayed. I also tried to sync the `shadow` & `passwd` files, but there's still an error:

```
$ wc -l /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
  17 /etc/passwd
  17 /etc/shadow
  34 total
```

Comment: Compare the passwd and the shadow file manually line by line. Maybe some lines are out of order....

Comment: @Dayjay i has manually checked 2 files, they has same line order

Answer (score 1):

Check the integrity of /etc/passwd and related files with `pwck`. Do the same for group related files with `grpck`.

Comment: i ran `pwck` & `grpck`, but nothing was displayed :(

Answer (score 0):

If you got that error it is because the user you wanted to add previously existed and was deleted. And since it existed in the `/etc/passwd` file, the system automatically created an encrypted passwd in the `/etc/shadow` for that user.
Therefore when the user was deleted from the `/etc/passwd`, the encrypted passwd should have been deleted from the `/etc/shadow file`.

Put it this way: you can't add a user with the `useradd` command if a password already exists for that user in the `/etc/shadow` file.

Go to the `/etc/shadow` file and delete the password line for that user and then
you'll be able to add the user.

Comment: Make sure to also check /etc/user_attr. This is checked in the useradd process too.

Answer (score 0):

Check file  /etc/user_attr. If there is an entry for oracle, hash it out and run useradd command. User will get created and then enable the entry in  /etc/user_attr.
It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your server is a NIS client and hence adding local users maybe forbidden. Just check if this is a part of NIS domain.